# Positioning absolute div with title

Tags: html, css, position, height, absolute

I am working on some html code but came to a problem. This is what we are trying to do:

We will have multiple images in a single row(list), the width will be fullwidth, so they will change height regarding the browser width. This works ok, but we have a problem with setting the caption on to them. We want to set the caption in the middle of this image, so that it is vertically in the middle and in the center horizontally. It would also need to take the full image height.

Here is what we have and what we want to have:

[Example here JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nxL7pwq2/5/)

Code:

```
body {
    background: #fafafa;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%; 
    height: auto;
    float: left;
}

.title-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.title-wrapper a {
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.wanted-result {
    width: 100%; 
    margin-top: 30px; 
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
    float: left;
}

.get-result {
    width: 100%; 
    margin-bottom: 30px; 
    float: left;
}

<div class="get-result">
    This is what get:
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="list-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="http://s5.favim.com/orig/52/winter-nature-small-canon-eos-7d-Favim.com-474348.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://s5.favim.com/orig/52/winter-nature-small-canon-eos-7d-Favim.com-474348.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://s5.favim.com/orig/52/winter-nature-small-canon-eos-7d-Favim.com-474348.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://s5.favim.com/orig/52/winter-nature-small-canon-eos-7d-Favim.com-474348.jpg" /></li>
            <li><img src="http://s5.favim.com/orig/52/winter-nature-small-canon-eos-7d-Favim.com-474348.jpg" /></li>  

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="title-wrapper">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wanted-result">
    This is what we want to get:
</div>
<img src="http://s12.postimg.org/ibhy38epp/birds.jpg" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: How would you like it if the `.title-wrapper` class in CSS had a `width: 20%; left: 40%;` and line height equal to the image height, in this case  ~130px. You can probably make it dynamic accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't want to replace the middle list item, i might have 10 of them for example, I just want to put a title above them, that is in the middle of the list and it takes the width regarding the text inputed. It might go over 1 and half list item for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can place `a` tag inside `li` right after image and wrap text into `span`:

```
        <li><img src="http://s5.favim.com/orig/52/winter-nature-small-canon-eos-7d-Favim.com-474348.jpg" />
            <a href=""><span>Title</span></a>
        </li>
```

Add next css:

```
.list-wrapper li > a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.list-wrapper li > a > span { 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 42%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can see implementation in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/fh8pqaez/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I dont want to replace the middle list item, i might have 10 of them for example, I just want to put a title above them, that is in the middle of the list and it takes the width regaring the text inputed. It might go over 1 and half list item for example.

Answer (score 1):

Put The `style` property of `<a>`

`<a style="text-align: center; left: 50%; background-color: white; padding: 65px 0px 0px; position: absolute; width: 10%; height: 49%;" href="#">Title</a>`

Try this, it'll work, you will get what you want.
If you want to play with height and width manipulate the `height` and `width` property.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky as trying to cover a dynamically sized image is almost impossible without some sort of overlap. Use position relative for the text and adjust it from the top 45-50% depending on how big your text is, then you can use vw to try to cover up the image best you can.

```
.title-wrapper a {
    position: relative;
    top: 46%;
    color: #000;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 6.8vw 9vw;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```